# How to merge 5 columns of a dataframe into one long column of new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, weather

I have a dataframe, `BaseResult` that contains 41 years of daily temperature data (41 rows x 365 columns) where rows represent years and columns represent days. I want to merge every 5 columns centered on each day into one long column so that I have a new dataframe, `RollingPercentile` that is (200 rows x 365 columns). Here the column for Jan 03 will contain data from Jan 01-05, the column for Jan 04 will contain data for Jan 02-06, etc. So far I've only been able to merge columns horizontally i.e. 3 values in one column instead of one longer column with 3x the data.

```
source_col_loc=BaseResult.columns.get_loc('01-01')
BaseResult['01-01']=BaseResult.iloc[:,source_col_loc+1:source_col_loc+4].apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
```

How can I do this so that they merge vertically and so that I can iterate through the entire data frame? My ultimate goal is to calculate the 90th percentile of each column containing the 5 days worth of data centered on the day indexed by doing `Percentile90=RollingPercentile.percentile(0.9)` so that I end up with an array of 365 values.

Comment: while I try to solve your question: here is the code to generate a dataframe similar to yours. 
If you edit your question, would be easier to answer.

`day = [i for i in range(366)] `
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,42,size=(42, 366)), columns=list(day))`

Answer (score 0):

use windows to perform your calculation

rolling percentiles aggregate over multiple rows of data to get a value.

```
df.rolling(window=window, min_periods=min_periods).quantile(perc)

df.rolling(window=window, min_periods=min_periods).mean()

df.rolling(window=window, min_periods=min_periods).std()

df1.rolling(window=window, min_periods=min_periods).apply(lambda x: 
stats.linregress(x, df2), raw=False)
```

these are some windows and types of rolling aggregations that you can apply

Comment: I need to aggregate over both rows and columns. Is it possible to do that using these?